# Auto-populate other column cells based on a column in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics

I am trying to auto-populate some values in my google sheet

If column B has the value as 'Steel', it should auto populate 'NA' in column C and D.
On the other hand if the value in Column B is filled as 'Copper', Column E and F should become 'NA'.

I cannot use a formula because then I cannot input other values in those columns. For example, I need to select values from dropdown in column E and F when Column B is 'Steel'.

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FtWF.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 2) {
    if (e.value == "Copper") {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart + 1, 1, 4).setValues([["", "", "NA", "NA"]]);
    }
    else if (e.value == "Steel") {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart + 1, 1, 4).setValues([["NA", "NA", "", ""]]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit. I even tried using it on trigger but somehow it doesn't seem to work. Sheet link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kQWgLKrJCoVjxYjrLx-7eby2s97w9hWXXH8exIwg9zw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I just tested it and it worked perfectly using the onEdit simple trigger.  You do not need to create a trigger for it you simple need to use the onEdit simple trigger by naming it onEdit(e) .  You cannot run it from a menu or the script editor you need to to save it and set the sheet name.  I put a dataValidation from a liist of Copper,Steel in column 2 and that did the trick.  My guess is that you are unfamiliar with using this sort of script.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you can implement a simple trigger (onEdit) to auto populate your sheet every time the material property is changed. You can do it like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var material = e.value;
  if (column == 2) {
    if (material == "Copper") {
      sh.getRange(row, column+1,1,2).setValue("");
      sh.getRange(row, column+3,1,2).setValue("NA");
    }
    else if (material == "Steel") {
      sh.getRange(row, column+1,1,2).setValue("NA");
      sh.getRange(row, column+3,1,2).setValue("");
    }
  }
}
```

In this script, I have added .setValue("") to reset the other fields with no "NA".

To test the script, I have created a simple replication:

[image]

When I set the Material property to "Steel", I get:

[image]

On the other hand, when I change the Material property to "Copper", I get:

[image]

You can refer to the [Simple Triggers Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en) and [Event Objects Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events?hl=en) for more details.